# Caliburn Micro Bind Child Control to Property

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a View that loads up fine with Caliburn Micro however inside of the view I have a SmithHtml editor that I need to bind the BindingContent Dependency Property to.

I have a combo box that holds a list of the files to edit and in my view model I update the currently selected item whenever the combo box selection is changed, but the SmithHtml Editor BindingContent never updates.

Below is the ViewModel:

```
    using Caliburn.Micro;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace PracticumEmailer.Ui.ViewModels
{

    public class EditTemplatesViewModel : Screen
    {
        private readonly string _templatesPath =
            Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
                Properties.Settings.Default.TemplateDirectory);
        private readonly BindableCollection<string> _files;

        private string _currentTemplate;
        private string _currentContent;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public EditTemplatesViewModel()
        {
            var info = new DirectoryInfo(_templatesPath);
            _files =
                new BindableCollection<string>(
                    info.EnumerateFiles("*.html").Select(fi => fi.Name.Remove(fi.Name.IndexOf('.')).ToUpper()));
        }

        public BindableCollection<String> Files { get { return _files; } }

        public String ContentHtml
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentContent;
            }
            set
            {
                _currentContent = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ContentHtml);
            }
        }

        public void OnSelectionChanged(string file)
        {
            _currentTemplate = Path.Combine(_templatesPath, string.Format("{0}.html", file.ToLower()));
            ContentHtml = File.ReadAllText(_currentTemplate);
        }
    }
    }
```

And Here is the XAML:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="PracticumEmailer.Ui.Views.EditTemplatesView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:htmlEditor="clr-namespace:Smith.WPF.HtmlEditor;assembly=Smith.WPF.HtmlEditor"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ComboBox x:Name="Files" cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action OnSelectionChanged(Files.SelectedItem)]"></ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <htmlEditor:HtmlEditor BindingContent="{Binding Path=ContentHtml}"></htmlEditor:HtmlEditor>

    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

This ended up working:

```
<htmlEditor:HtmlEditor BindingContent="{Binding BindingContent, Mode=TwoWay}"></htmlEditor:HtmlEditor>
```

Comment: do you have CM debugging turned on? I assume you are using V2.01

Comment: Also are you seeing a OnSelectionChanged firing when you select your template file?

Comment: @mvermef No I don't have debugging turned on. I didn't even know about this. Yes the OnSelectionChanged is firing fine and the ContentHtml property is being set just fine when I updated it on the SlectionChanged event.

Comment: To turn on debugging for CM in the Configure Method of your bootstrapper. ````LogManager.GetLog = type => new DebugLog(type);```` then if you want to debug information while running without break points and want to know the value of something ````ILog logger = LogManager.GetLog(typeof<ViewModelInQuestion>);````  Once you have an idea of what is being show in the debug console it will be glaring obvious if something isn't working with CM correctly.

Comment: ````logger.Info(format, value)````; logger has more options than that but it is a start to see if there is actually a binding issue with CM on that out of box control.  I did look at the control on codeplex it should work as you have it but it won't be write able till you set its Mode = "TwoWay"

Comment: @mvermef Awesome thank you I will turn on debugging and try it when I get home tonight.

Comment: A quick test to see if it's an issue with the view model or view would be to replace the html editor control with a textblock. If you see the html then it's the editor control causing the issue otherwise the view model.

Comment: Just so you guys know simply adding the TwoWay binding appeared to fix it.

Comment: If someone wants to type up an answer I'll go ahead and accept it.